# Ninject's "InRequestScope()" isn't working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, unit-of-work

I'm running MVC5 application with Entity Framework+Repositories+UnitOfWork layer, Services layer and Web Presentation layer. Ninject is used for resolving dependancies, services bindings are all in separate module which is listed below

```
public class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<EfUnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();

        Bind<ICategoriesService>().To<CategoriesService>();
        .
        .
        other bindings...
    }
}
```

The problem is that for request which requires 2+ services, each service creates another unitOfWork despite the "InRequestScope", but when I switch to:

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<EfUnitOfWork>().InScope(c => System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
```

Everythings works perfectly and only one instance of unitOfWork is created for handling the request.
What could be possibly wrong ?